# Websocket with laravel echo incorrect app_key

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

i'm using laravel echo to make push notification and it returns me

```
 local.ERROR: Pusher error: auth_key should be a valid app key
```

May you give me any hint what's wrong with my code.

bootstrap.js

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ?? `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],

});
```

.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_APP_ID=abc
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
PUSHER_APP_HOST=127.0.0.1
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: try php artisan key:generate